# Linear congruences - system of two equations with two variables - solutions don't satisfy

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

$$9x+27y \equiv 3\pmod {102}$$
$$16x+4y \equiv 2\pmod {102}$$

Here's what I did. I subtracted the first equation from the second  to get

$$9x+27y \equiv 3\pmod {102}$$
$$7x-23y \equiv -1\pmod {102}$$

After that, I multiplied the first equation by $7$. Next, I added to it the second equation multiplied by $-9$ to eliminate $x$ from the first equation:

$$I = II \cdot -9 + I$$

The first equation now looks like this:

$$396y \equiv 30 \pmod {102}$$

I checked the solutions online, and this congruence has six solutions less than $m$ which are: $y=6,23,40,57,74,91$

For example. let's take $y=6$ for now. If I plug it in the second equation $16x+4y \equiv 2 (\mod 102)$, I get the congruence:

$$16x \equiv 80 \pmod {102}$$

The solutions of which are $x=5$, $x=56$.

Now, for $y=6$ we have $x=5$ and $x=56$.

**The problem**: I tried to test $x=5, y=6$ and it satisfies both of the starting linear congruences. However, $x=56, y=6$ satisfies only the second congruence.

What do I do now? I calculated all solutions and it came out that the $y=6, y=57$ share the same values for x. Same goes for $y=23, y=74$ and $y=40, y=91$. I doubt I made a mistake, so does it mean I only discard the solutions which don't satisfy both congruences?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't follow your math that closely.  Therefore, it is possible that you made an algebraic mistake.  Hypothetically, assume that you have made no algebraic mistake.  Then, your only mistake was conceptual.  That is, you start with a group of Premises for $(x,y)$ and reason that the premises imply that some conclusion must be satisfied.  However, this is generally a **one-way** implication.  That is, if the premises are satisfied, then the conclusion must hold, but **not necessarily vice-versa**.  ...see next comment

Comment: This means that when you reach a conclusion, each of the solutions to the conclusion are nothing more than **candidate solutions** to the original group of premises.  Each candidate solution must therefore be manually checked against the original premises to see whether (or not) that particular candidate solution satisfies the premises.

Comment: Note that $\gcd(9,102)=3>1$.  It follows that multiplying by $9$ isn't straightforward.   After all $2\times 0\equiv 0\pmod 6$ and $2\times 3\equiv 0 \pmod 6$.

Comment: @lulu What I did was multiply the second equation by -9 and immediately add it to the first one which I think is a regular transformation. It would be irregular if I only multiplied the second equation by -9 and _changed it_ (i.e. left it at that). At least that's what we are taught

Comment: Not following.  Say I wanted to solve $x\equiv 0 \pmod 6$.  Ok, the answer is obviously $\{0\}$ but suppose i tried to solve it by multiplying by $2$.  We'd then get $2x\equiv 0\pmod 6$ which has the solutions $\{0,3\}$, so just multiplying by $2$ gave rise to a spurious solution. Multiplying by zero-divisors is tricky.

Comment: Phrased more broadly, $A\equiv B\pmod n\implies kA\equiv kB\pmod n$ for any $k\pmod n$, but the converse is only true if $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

Comment: On the one hand, I agree with the insights in the comments of @lulu.  On the other hand, you are asking for trouble if you try to *memorize* or *learn* which implications are two-way implications and which implications are one-way implications.  The safest course is to always assume that implications are one-way, and then automatically construe the derived solutions as candidate solutions.

Comment: You ought to solve the system mod 2, then solve it mod 3,  then solve it mod 17. If this gives solutions in all three cases, combine (carefully) as Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Note that, for each prime, you may reduce the coefficients mod that prime. So, for example, mod 2  just gives $x+y \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$   the second equation becomes a tautology $0 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and  is ignored.

Comment: Correct: Keep only the solutions that satisfy BOTH congruences. You seem to believe that if you eliminate x first and find all values for y, and then you substitute those values for y in one of the equations and find all the values for x, what you find are solutions for the system of equations (meaning, the (x, y) pairs will automatically also satisfy the first equation). This is generally the expectation if you solve equations in real numbers, or modulo a prime number. ("Over a field") But 102 is not prime, so that implication (which you expect) does not hold.

Comment: [Your question is similar to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4295540/system-of-three-linear-congruences-with-three-variables/4295861#4295861).

All the solutions of $(x,y) $ are $$(x \bmod{102}, y\bmod{102}) = (5, 6), (22, 91), (39, 74), (56, 57), (73, 40), (90, 23) $$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{cases}9x+27y-3=102 k\\16x+4y-2=102m\end{cases}$

Which gives:

$x=\frac{17(27m-4k)+7}{66}\Rightarrow 66x\equiv 7\bmod 17$

$66\equiv 15\equiv -2 \bmod 17$

$\Rightarrow -2x\equiv 7\bmod 17\rightarrow 2x\equiv -7\equiv 10 \bmod 17$

$\Rightarrow x\equiv 5\bmod 17$

$y=\frac{17(16k-9m)+5}{66}$

$66y\equiv 5\bmod 17$

which finally gives :

$y\equiv 6\bmod 17$